# Assign to an ID more elements

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, iteration, coordinates

I'm new in C++. I need to assign iteratively to a progressive ID (int), 3 coordinates (int).
For example if I have ID=3, I assign to it coordinates={2,4,6}. 
Is there a structure in C++ to do It?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). For the coordinates you can use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map or unordered_map provide in stl if you are familiar with it. Just check it out they are pretty simple to implement.

use

```
map<int,vector<int>> m;
```

or

```
unordered_map<int,vector<int>> um;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `std::map` which "maps" an integer - your progressive ID - to a 3-tuple (since you need 3 coordinates only).

You can do it like this:

```
map<int, tuple<int, int, int> > my_map; // id, coordinates
```

Make sure to `#include <map>` and `#include <tuple>` which are required for the definitions of `std::map` and `std::tuple`.

An example on how to use this:

```
map<int, tuple<int, int, int> > my_map;
int id = 27;
auto coord = make_tuple(3, 4, 5);
my_map[id] = coord;

cout << "ID: 27, coordinates: " << get<0>(my_map[id]) << get<1>(my_map[id])
                                << get<2>(my_map[id]); //prints 345
```